# Recursion error when building beam pipeline with dataflow runner when using custom ptransform

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-beam

I built and managed to run a satisfactory pipeline locally with beam, and I am ready to send the job to DataFlow.

I planned to just pickle my session with the `save_main_session` pipeline option, however I run into a recursion error when trying to do so. After a couple of trial and error I managed to narrow it down to the way I define my `ptransform_fn`, with a decorator.

Please find below a minimal reproducible example

```py
# my_script.py

from typing import Set
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, SetupOptions
from apache_beam.transforms.ptransform import ptransform_fn


@ptransform_fn
def my_function(pcoll):
    return pcoll | beam.Create([1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = PipelineOptions()
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        p | my_function()
```

The full traceback is quite long but ends with `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`

(Note that this is the `save_main_session=True`) option that enables this error, so I can run this `python -m my_script` using the local runner and will run into the `RecursionError`)

As the `ptransform_fn` is actually making `my_function` behave in an "unpythonic" way (being called without the argument it was defined), it seems like the pickler library has a problem with this.

So my final questions are:

- Is this expected behavior ? Should I stick to defining classes which inherit from Beam.PTransform if I want to use the save_main_session ?
- Is there a simple way (as setting up a pipeline option) to be able to pickle this script and run it on dataflow ?

Answer (score 1):

`save_main_session` is inherently a bit fragile; for anything non-trivial I recommend putting the logic in a named module that can be imported in your main script (and on your workers).

Answer (score 1):

Define a class inheriting from `beam.PTransform` instead worked for me. This takes care of pickle's issue with the function call being "unpythonic".

```
class MyFunction(beam.PTransform):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def expand(pcoll):
        return pcoll | beam.Create([1])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = PipelineOptions()
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        p | MyFunction()
```